# Regex: Get Filename Without Extension in One Shot?

Tags: regex, syntax

I want to get just the filename using regex, so I've been trying simple things like

```
([^\.]*)
```

which of course work only if the filename has one extension. But if it is `adfadsfads.blah.txt` I just want `adfadsfads.blah`. How can I do this with regex?

In regards to David's question, 'why would you use regex' for this, the answer is, 'for fun.' In fact, the code I'm using is simple

```
length_of_ext = File.extname(filename).length
filename = filename[0,(filename.length-length_of_ext)]
```

but I like to learn regex whenever possible because it always comes up at Geek cocktail parties.

Comment: Daniel, in such a case I would recommend you to purchase a tool like RegexBuddy. It is more fun to play with regex if you have a tool like that. You can even debug regular expressions in such a tool. A really recommend that.

Comment: Thanks David. I use Regex Coach, which does really nicely.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this:

```
(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)
```

This will:

- Capture filenames that start with a dot (e.g. `.logs` is a file named `.logs`, not a file extension), which is common in Unix.
- Gets everything but the last dot: `foo.bar.jpeg` gets you `foo.bar`.
- Handles files with no dot: `secret-letter` gets you `secret-letter`.

---

Note: as commenter j_random_hacker suggested, this performs as advertised, but you might want to precede things with an anchor for readability purposes.

Comment: There is a good explanation of this one at http://www.movingtofreedom.org/2008/04/01/regex-match-filename-base-and-extension/

Comment: The star should be a plus, I think - though it is not clear what a file called 'log.' should return.

Comment: Although this does work as advertised, could I suggest prepending a "^" anchor just for readability's sake? Without the anchor, a programmer seeing this regex for the first time needs to perform a detailed analysis to verify that returned match always starts at the start of the string.

Comment: To have only one capture: (.+?)(?:\.[^.]*$|$)

Comment: this files when using something like path/to/file/myfile.csv

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with file-paths, only file-names?

Answer (score 4):

Everything followed by a dot followed by one or more characters that's not a dot, followed by the end-of-string:

```
(.+?)\.[^\.]+$
```

The everything-before-the-last-dot is grouped for easy retrieval.

If you aren't 100% sure every file will have an extension, try:

```
(.+?)(\.[^\.]+$|$)
```

Comment: It does not match a filename which has no extension

Answer (score 3):

how about 2 captures one for the end and one for the filename.

eg.

```
(.+?)(?:\.[^\.]*$|$)
```

Comment: That's all fine, but since I'll be throwing out the filename, why bother? I would like a regex that just gets the filename.

Comment: This one also will not match a filename containing no extension.

Answer (score 3):

```
^(.*)\\(.*)(\..*)$
```

1. Gets the Path without the last `\`
2. The file without extension
3. The the extension with a `.`

Examples:

`c:\1\2\3\Books.accdb`
`(c:\1\2\3)(Books)(.accdb)`

Does not support multiple `.` in file name
Does support `.` in file path

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is a bit outdated, however, I had some trouble finding a good source and wound up making the regex myself. To save whoever may find this time,

If you're looking for a ~standalone~ regex

This will match the extension without the dot

`\w+(?![\.\w])`

This will always match the file name *if* it has an extention

`[\w\. ]+(?=[\.])`

Comment: There are a few bugs with these patterns. Specifically, `|` and `+` don't work inside character classes (`[]`).

Comment: whoops, fixed it. thanks, this is why i google regexes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure why I would use regular expression for this. If I know for example that the string is a full filepath, then I would use another API to get the file name. Regular expressions are very powerfull but at the same time quite complex (you have just proved that by asking how to create such a simple regex). Somebody said: you had a problem that you decided to solve it using regular expressions. Now you have two problems.

Think again. If you are on .NET platform for example, then take a look at [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class.

Comment: Well, that's not much fun, is it? Anyway, adjusted the question to your answer, please see above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used this pattern for simple search:

```
^\s*[^\.\W]+$
```

for this text:

```
file.ext
   fileext

   file.ext.ext
 file.ext
fileext
```

It finds `fileext` in the second and last lines.
I applied it in a text tree view of a folder (with spaces as indents).

Answer (score 0):

Just the name of the file, without path and suffix.

```
^.*[\\|\/](.+?)\.[^\.]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(?<=[\\\w\d-:]*\\)([\w\d-:]*)(?=\.[\.\w\d-:]*)
```

Captures just the filename of any kind within an entire filepath. Purposefully excludes the file path and the file extension

Etc:

```
C:\Log\test\bin\fee105d1-5008-410c-be39-883e5e40a33d.pdf
```

- Doesn't capture *(C:\Log\test\bin)*
- Captures (**fee105d1-5008-410c-be39-883e5e40a33d**)
- Doesn't capture *(.pdf)*

Answer (score 0):

This RegExp works for me:

```
(.+(?=\..+$))|(.+[^\.])
```

Results (bold means match):

- **test**.txt
- **test 234!**.something123
- **.test**
- **.test**.txt
- **test.test2**.txt
- .