# Why would regex to separate filename from extension not work in ColdFusion?

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to retrieve a filename without the extension in ColdFusion.  I am using the following function:
`REMatchNoCase( "(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)" , "Doe, John 8.15.2012.docx" );`

I would like this to return an array like: `["Doe, John 8.15.2012","docx"]`
but instead I always get an array with one element - the entire filename:`["Doe, John 8.15.2012.docx"]`

I tried the regex string above on rexv.org and it works as expected, but not on ColdFusion. I got the string from this SO question: [Regex: Get Filename Without Extension in One Shot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624870/regex-question-get-filename-without-extension-in-one-shotin)

Does ColdFusion use a different syntax? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Why you're not getting expected results...

The reason you are getting a one-item array with the whole filename is because your pattern matches the entire filename, and matches once.

It *is* capturing the two groups, but [**rematch**](http://cfdocs.org/rematch) returns arrays of matches, not arrays of the captured groups, so you don't see those groups.

#### How to solve the problem...

If you are dealing with simple files (i.e. no `.htaccess` or similar), then the simplest solution is to just use...

```
ListLast( filename , '.' )
```

....to get only the file extension and to get the name without extension you can do...

```
rematch( '.+(?=\.[^.]+$)' , filename )
```

This uses a lookahead to ensure there is a `.` followed by at least one non-`.` at the end of the string, but (since it's a lookahead) it is excluded from the match (so you only get the pre-extension part in your match).

To deal with non-extensioned files (e.g. `.htaccess` or `README`) you can modify the above regex to `.+(?=(?:\.[^.]+)?$)` which basically does the same thing except making the extension optional. However, there isn't a trivial way to get update the ListLast method for these (guess you'd need to check `len(extension) LT len(filename)-1` or similar).

#### *(optional)* Accessing captured groups...

If you want to get at the actual captured groups, the closest native way to do this in CF is using the [**refind**](http://cfdocs.org/refind) function, with the fourth argument set to true - however, this only gives you positions and lengths - requiring that you use [mid](http://cfdocs.org/mid) to extract them yourself.

For this reason (amongst many others), I've created an [improved regex implementation for CF, called cfRegex](http://cfregex.net/), which lets you return the group text directly (i.e. no messing around with mid).

If you wanted to use cfRegex, you can do so with your original pattern like so:

```
RegexMatch( '(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)' , filename , 1 , 0 , 'groups' )
```

Or with named arguments:

```
RegexMatch( pattern='(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)' , text=filename , returntype='groups' )
```

And you get returned an array of matches, within each element being an array of the captured groups for that match.

If you're doing lots of regex work dealing with captured groups, [cfRegex](http://cfregex.net) is definitely better than doing it with CF's re methods.

If all you care about is getting  the extension and/or the filename with extension excluded then the previous examples above are sufficient.

Comment: instead of using regex to find the file name w/o the extension you could always just do `replace(filename,ListLast(filename,'.'),'')` this wouldn't work if you file was named importantdocument.doc though

Comment: You've given your own reason why this isn't suitable in the same comment? :/ If you were getting both parts and didn't want regex you could do `left(filename,len(filename)-len(extension))` to remove the extension from the filename.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks for the heads up on cfRegex as well. It's overkill for this problem, but I'll keep an eye on it for future projects.

Comment: Yeah, definitely overkill for this, but as I mentioned, this was exactly the type of problem that spawned it, so I thought it worth mentioning. :)

Comment: Peter, how do you know the value of len(extension) ? I was just offering a comment on another way to perform this.

Comment: You could also do ListFirst(filename,'.') as well. There are literally a hundred ways you could do this.

Answer (score 1):

@Peter's response is great, however the approach is perhaps a bit longer-winded than necessary.  One can do this with `reMatch()` with a slight tweak to the regex.

```
<cfscript>
    param name="URL.filename";

    sRegex = "^.+?(?=(?:\.[^.]+?)?$)";

    aMatch = reMatch(sRegex, URL.filename);

    writeDump(aMatch);
</cfscript>
```

This works on the following filename patterns:

- foo.bar
- foo
- .htaccess
- John 8.15.2012.docx

Explanation of the regex:

^ From the beginning of the string

.+? One or more (+) characters (.), but the fewest (?) that will work with the rest of the regex.  This is the file name.

(?=) Look ahead.  Make sure the stuff in here appears in the string, but don't actually match it. This is the key bit to NOT return any file extension that might be present.

(?: Group this stuff together, but don't remember it for a back reference.

. A dot.  This is the separator between file name and file extension.

[^.]+?  One or more (+) single ([]) non-dot characters (^.), again matching the fewest possible (?) that will allow the regex as a whole to work.

? (This is the one after the (?:) group).  Zero or one of those groups: ie: zero or one file extensions.

$ To the end of the string

I've only tested with those four file name patterns, but it seems to work OK.  Other people might be able to finetune it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by longer-winded? The final section is entirely optional, and the first two I was wondering if I'd given enough detail. :S

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the regex for unextensioned files (though using ListLast will still fail on those), but I specifically didn't use lazy quantifiers because they have no benefit here and will slow down execution.

Comment: Precisely *because* it was so long as to need to be broken down into sections marked "optional", etc ;-).  I don't think the performance of lazy quantifiers is going to be so relevant when parsing a *file name*.  That said, it's a reasonable theoretical observation to make if measured with a grounding in the real world (ie: unlikely to be very relevant in this case).

Comment: It could easily be used in a function which in turn gets used whilst looping through lots of files, and the performance of the different quantifiers has a bigger impact than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

A few more ways of achieving the same result. They all execute in roughly the same amount of time.

```
<cfscript>
str = 'Doe, John 8.15.2012.docx';

// sans regex
arr1 = [
    reverse( listRest( reverse( str ), '.' ) ),
    listLast( str, '.' )
];

// using Java String lastIndexOf()
arr2 = [
    str.substring( 0, str.lastIndexOf( '.' ) ),
    str.substring( str.lastIndexOf( '.' ) + 1 )
];

// using listToArray with non-filename safe character replace
arr3 = listToArray( str.replaceAll( '\.([^\.]+)$', '|$1' ), '|' );
</cfscript>
```