# How can I remove a filename extension from a string in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to remove the extension from a string with the following structure:

```
name.stl
```

I found that I can use the `basename` method to get the string. The problem is that I am not using the file path, and I already have the string with the name. I just need to delete the extension from the string.

It seems to me that a regular expression would be a great option to detect the dot and delete everything from it to the end.

How can I use a regex to do this on Ruby on Rails 4?

Comment: `s.sub(/\.[^.]+\z/, '')`

Comment: Use regex in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/624877/2245697
In Ruby, you can use `string.scan(/(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)/).first.first`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What problem are you having with `File.basename`? `File.basename("name.stl", ".stl")` returns `"name"`, as does `File.basename("name.stl", ".*")`. Is there some other result you want?

Comment: Can you ever have multiple extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways, here are 2, with [`rpartition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rpartition) and a regex:

```
s = "more.name.stl"
puts s.sub(/\.[^.]+\z/, '')  # => more.name
puts s.rpartition('.').first # => more.name
```

See the [IDEONE  demo](http://ideone.com/7QDjQK)

The `rpartition` way is clear, and as for the regex, it matches:

- `\.` - a dot
- `[^.]+` - one or more characters other than a dot
- `\z` - end of string.

Comment: The `rpartition` method worked like a charm, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the built-in methods. These will work correctly across different OSes:

```
filename = '/path/to/foo.bar'
File.basename(filename) # => "foo.bar"
File.extname(filename) # => ".bar"
File.basename(filename, File.extname(filename)) # => "foo"
```

And, in case you need the containing directory:

```
File.dirname(filename) # => "/path/to"
```

If you don't care, then a simple `split('.')` would work:

```
'foo.bar'.split('.').first # => "foo"
```

or

```
'foo.bar'[/^[^.]+/] # => "foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File.basename 'name.stl', '.stl'
```