# How to extract the filename from a string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am new in the regular expression and trying to extract the file name from a string which is basically a file path.

```
string = "input_new/survey/argentina-attributes.csv"
string_required = argentina-attributes
```

i know i can do this by below code.

```
string.split('/')[2].split('.')[0]
```

but I am looking to do this by using regular expression so if in future the formate of the path changes(input_new/survey/path/path/argentina-attributes.csv) should not affect the output.

i know kind of similar question asked before but I am looking for a pattern which will work for my use case.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52966261/3832970), `r'^.*[\\/](.+?)\.[^.]+$'` looks to be what you want.

Comment: I suggest you use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library (in the std library), it is meant to manipulate paths and is (in my opinion) very convenient. A simple `Path(string).name` will do

Comment: `>>> re.search(r"^.*[\\/](.+?)\.[^.]+$", "input_new/survey/argentina-attributes.csv").group(0)
'input_new/survey/argentina-attributes.csv' not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "input_new/survey/argentina-attributes.csv"
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^\/]+(?=\.)',string) # or re.findall(r'([^\/]+)\.',string)
['argentina-attributes']
```

Referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9363181/8353711)

Comment: Thanks it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string = "input_new/survey/argentina-attributes.csv"
new_string = string.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
print(new_string)
```

Comment: thanks, this will work but how to do this using a regular expression.