# how to remove after dot letters on dart using Regular expression?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    String abc = 'abc.jpg';
    //or
    String abc = 'abc.png';
    //or
    String abc = 'abc.xxxx';
```

How to remove **.png** or **.jpg** or **.xxxx**?

I tried this way. But not working

```
print(abc.replaceAll(RegExp("\.\$"),''));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:-

```
print(abc.split(RegExp(r"(\.+)"))[0]);
```

Hope it will work

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
filename = abc.split(".")[0]
```

It's that simple :)

Comment: I want to do it using regExp.

Answer (score 3):

Try with :

```
print(abc.replaceAll('.', ''));

or 

with Regx: 

print(abc.replaceAll(RegExp('[^a-z0-9_]+'),''));
```

Comment: I want to do it using regExp.

Answer (score 1):

With regular expression:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/624877/8619512
```

> Try this:
>
> (.+?)(.[^.]*$|$) This will:
>
> Capture filenames that start with a dot (e.g. ".logs" is a file named
>   ".logs", not a file extension), which is common in Unix. Gets
>   everything but the last dot: "foo.bar.jpeg" gets you "foo.bar".
>   Handles files with no dot: "secret-letter" gets you "secret-letter".

Comment: how to use expression on dart?

Answer (score 0):

```
 str.toStringAsFixed(0);
```

simply add this to your string
it removes the string after the dot(.).