# Regex for extracting just a name of image from the img src

Tags: regex

I have img url like this:

`<img src="https://www.example.com/examplee/media/photo/v1/something.png">`

and I want to extract from here just a name of this image without extension `.png` or `.jpg`

what I tried:

```
/[^/\\]+(?:jpg|png)/gi
```

but this gave me `something.png` but as I said above, I need only name without the `.png`

Can someone please help me? I am totally inexperienced with regex.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it mandatory to use regular expression? Can't you just parse the URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex: Get Filename Without Extension in One Shot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624870/regex-get-filename-without-extension-in-one-shot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive look ahead.
Try this

```
 [^\/\\]+(?=\.png|\.jpg)
```

You can find info about it here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is it!

Comment: @FrankMaximus You're welcome. Please mark as answer if you are sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this
`(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)`

This regex can deal with any extention

Reference: [Regex: Get Filename Without Extension in One Shot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624870/regex-get-filename-without-extension-in-one-shot)